Sort hierarchic Parent / Child list in Python
I have a small concern about managing hierarchy in a Parent/Child relationship in PYTHON.
To give some context, I have a table made up of x fields. Here are the ones I'm interested in:

product_id
parent_ref
child_ref

This table represents the flat structure of several products (product_id = a car model).
Where the first parent would be the body, on which we install doors, an engine cradle, an engine, which is itself made up of hundreds of parts etc...
Some car models reuse parts from other vehicles, same engine, same clutch...
This is my case here, I have a file of about 1.8 million lines that show me the structure of each of my products.
I want to create a notion of "Level" which is calculated according to the position in the structure. For example, I know that all the first children, i.e. level 1, have the value "-1" in the parent column.
`Ex: 
Product_id           Parent_ref            child_ref
BMW316E46              -1                  150001-01    --> First parent
BMW316E46              -1                  150001-02    --> Second parent
BMW316E46          150001-01             140009-01    --> First parent first child...
BMW316E46          150001-01             140017-01    --> First parent second child...
BMW316E46          150001-01             140018-01`   --> Each child can be (or not) a parent as well

My aim is to draw up a structure for each product (Product_id) with a level column for each child, which will depend on the parent, and which will be visual. In other words, the identation of the child will be relative to the parent (I don't know in advance how many levels there may be).
Something like this :
Product_id    Parent_ref     Child_ref    Level (with visual identation)
BMW316E46       -1          150001-01     1
BMW316E46    150001-01    140009-01     __2
BMW316E46    150001-01    140017-01     __2
BMW316E46    140017-01    140017-01     ____3
BMW316E46       -1          150001-02     1
BMW316E46    150001-02    140009-01     __2
BMW316E46    150001-02    140017-01     __2

I tried something like this in Python to create an array for each loop to find out the different childs, but it works only for the first loop, because i need to separate the differents childs of each parents...
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")


for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['parent_ref'] == "'-1":
        array_lvl_1.append(row['child_ref'])
        parent_level = alc[count]
        df.loc[index, 'level'] = parent_level
        count += 1


for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['parent_ref'] in array_lvl_1:
        for value in array_lvl_1:
            array_lvl_1_1.append(row['child_ref'])
            df.loc[index, 'level'] = alc[count2]
            count2 += 1

But it's not recursive, and it forces me to create as many tables as there are levels, and I don't know the number of levels in advance.

Since this is a graph problem, I would use networkx with help of topological_generations to get the depths of each node and dfs_edges to generate the list of edges in a DFS order:
import networkx as nx

def make_hierarchy(g):
    G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(g, create_using=nx.DiGraph,
                                source='Parent_ref', target='Child_ref')
    depth = {n: f'{"_"*(d-1)}{d}' for d, l in
             enumerate(nx.topological_generations(G))
             for n in l}
    return (pd
       .DataFrame(nx.dfs_edges(G), columns=['Parent_ref', 'Child_ref'])
       .assign(Product_id=g.name,
               Level=lambda d: d['Child_ref'].map(depth)
              )
    )[['Product_id', 'Parent_ref', 'Child_ref', 'Level']]

# compute the hierarchy per group
out = df.groupby('Product_id', group_keys=False).apply(make_hierarchy)

# optional, left justify the strings
out['Level'] = out['Level'].str.ljust(out['Level'].str.len().max())

Output:
  Product_id   Parent_ref    Child_ref Level
0  BMW316E46           -1  150001-01  1  
1  BMW316E46  150001-01  140009-01   _2 
2  BMW316E46  150001-01  140017-01   _2 
3  BMW316E46  140017-01  140018-01   __3
4  BMW316E46           -1  150001-02   1  

Used input (slightly different from that in the question to have 3 levels):
0  BMW316E46           -1  150001-01
1  BMW316E46           -1  150001-02
2  BMW316E46  150001-01  140009-01
3  BMW316E46  150001-01  140017-01
4  BMW316E46  140017-01  140018-01

Graph:


Hi, sir, first of all i wanted to thank you a lot, because the result on the large data set is almost exactly what i wanted to be.
Is there any way I can contact you ?

@user24560168 you can provide your comments here, or edit the question if you need to add extra information.

Ok so two more things on this topic, my goal is to do this on a whole table, with a different Product_id, the original .csv file is 1.8mio lines, and there are many different Product_id. So i need to do this structure for each different Product_id.
Also one really important thing is to keep the order of the structure (the imbrication) while displaying the data on Power Bi (filtered on one product) si i probably need to add one more column where i can filter the data to keep the structure. If you have any idea.
Ty so much for your help.

And also wich graph type did you use ? I'm very new to all of this and don't know how to do this ...

@user24560168 "So i need to do this structure for each different Product_id." -> my code already does that ;) "one really important thing is to keep the order of the structure" -> I'm not sure what this really means, this should be addressed in a separate question if needed. For the code to plot the graph, see here

Okay, thanks a lot man, i edit the code you send me to make my csv file an input file. But the problem is that even if i'm doing the hierarchy on few cols of the input file, then i loose all the data of the other columns in the output file. It seems that the data is just ignored

The output DataFrame doesn't have the same number of rows as the input, if you want to keep some of the original columns you would need to merge

The output frame have exactly the same number of rows*
But the program only uses the given cols, and even with a merge it's actually not working. I don't know really why ...

One last thing, there is an ID column in the csv input file, I absolutely need to keep in the "out" dataframe, do you have an idea ?
I spend the whole day on this not finding any solutions...
The ID is just 1/2/3/4/5/6/etc to 1.8MIO just the line number

You can probably merge back the original DataFrame, something like out.merge(df[['ID', 'Product_id', Parent_ref', 'Child_ref']], on=['Product_id', Parent_ref', 'Child_ref'])
