Python Dataframe columns problem (disapear)
From a previous question I asked, I wanted to create and sort a certain Parent/Child hierarchy recursively.
With the huge help of one member, he find me a solution to complete this work.
But, yeah there is a but, The input file is a .csv file, with 18 columns.
The previous solutions only uses two columns (Parent and Child) and the output file just get these two columns + the column we've created to represent the hierarchy.
Here is the link of the previous topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78364917/sort-hierarchic-parent-child-list-in-python
My goal was to simply add my new column (created with the previous answer) and keep all the original DATA.
The problem is : The data from the original .csv file doesn't have any unique ID, so I can't merge old and new Dataframe together.
I've also tried to add the columns manually, here is the code :
def make_hierarchy(g):
    G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(g, create_using=nx.DiGraph,
                                source='REF_ARTICLE_PERE', target='REF_ARTICLE_FILS', **edge_attr=True**)
    
    def dfs_with_level(node, level, order, parent_order, max_depth):
        # Here I tried to modify the hierarchy_data squeletton, but no success
        hierarchy_data = [(g.name, node, level, parent_order + f'{order:0{max_depth}d}')]
        children = list(G.successors(node))
        if children:
            for i, child in enumerate(children, start=1):
                hierarchy_data.extend(dfs_with_level(child, level + 1, i, parent_order + f'{order:0{max_depth}d}' + '.', max_depth))
        return hierarchy_data
    
    hierarchy_data = []
    for node in G.nodes:
        if not list(G.predecessors(node)):
            max_depth = len(str(len(G)))
            hierarchy_data.extend(dfs_with_level(node, 1, 1, '', max_depth))
    # Here I tried to add columns in the dataframe, but they told me 4 cols passed, needed 5 somthing like this
    df_hierarchy = pd.DataFrame(hierarchy_data, columns=['REF_PRODUIT', 'REF_ARTICLE_FILS', 'Level', 'sorted_order'])

    # Add underscores to represent hierarchy levels visually (reverse order)
    max_level = df_hierarchy['Level'].max()
    df_hierarchy['Level'] = df_hierarchy['Level'].apply(lambda x: '_' * (x - 1) + str(x))
    
    return df_hierarchy


df = pd.read_csv('input.csv')

out = df.groupby('REF_PRODUIT', group_keys=False).apply(make_hierarchy)

out.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)

I set edge_attr=Yes to keep all the cols in the graph, but the problem is coming after this step.
While checking all the nodes, I would like to keep the data of the actual row, and add it to the df_hierarchy.
In the debugger I see the data in :
G.adj.values But it's all the data of all rows, not of only the current row.
And even if I find a way to get the data of the current row (to add it to the new DF) I'm not sure if I'm able to add it ...
I'm new to all of this Data manipulation, I'm a student, every help would be appreciated.
